# UIPopoverPresentationController is popoverVisible

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with a UIPopoverPresentationController and assigning the object like below code ,

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
     [myPopoverViewController popoverPresentationController];
```

I just want to check whether the popover is visible in an another method . Earlier in  UIPopoverController there is popoverVisible was available , is there any alternative for this .? and also i want to dismiss it in some other methods is there any alternative for dismissPopoverAnimated .? 
I just want to do something like this

```
if (presentationController != nil && presentationController.popoverVisible)
    {
        [presentationController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
```

any help appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

set like

```
  popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;

 [presentationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // or use self
```

and use delegate methods of

```
# pragma mark - Popover Presentation Controller Delegate

- (void)popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {

// called when a Popover is dismissed
}

- (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController {

// return YES if the Popover should be dismissed
// return NO if the Popover should not be dismissed
return YES;
}

 - (void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing  _Nonnull *)view {

// called when the Popover changes position
 }
```

for sample see this [tutorial](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-popovers-in-ios-9/)

Comment: UIPopoverPresentationController dosent have a dismissViewControllerAnimated , I tried self and but i am using number of UIPopoverPresentationController so it will get confused , I just want to check is the UIPopoverPresentationController object is visible already.

Answer (score 1):

All `UIViewController`s now have a `isBeingPresented` property, so rather than trying the check if the `UIPopoverPresentationController` is active, just check the `myPopoverViewController`

```
if myPopoverViewController.isBeingPresented {
    myPopoverViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: `UIPopoverPresentationController` is not a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: @svilansky, please clarify the point. Yes, those two types that you mentioned are different. However, @jjatie is saying that you can check `myPopoverViewController.isBeingPresented` because `myPopoverViewController` is a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hey, correct if I am wrong, but I think that isBeingPresented is true as long as the process of appearing of a popover is happening. The moment when the animation is done isBeingPresented is set to false. So it doesn't really replace popoverVisible property:( Has anyone solved that issue? Thanks